# Entity Framework complex multiple where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a database in which I'm trying to track document approvals.  Each document has 1 or more tasks.  Each task has 1 or more approvals.  Each approval has the ID to the assigned user as well as an assigned group.  Each user may belong to 1 or more groups and may have various permissions in each group. This information is stored in a 'many to many' relationship table with an additional field for permissions level. (user_id, group_id, permission_id)

For example, an approval to a task may be assigned to a user with ID=5 and to a group with ID=7.  In order for a user to approve this approval, they either must have a user ID of 5 or belong to group 7 with the permission to approve.

I'd like to create a query which selects all approvals either assigned to a particular user or belong to a group that a particular user have 'awareness' permissions to.

I have easily been able to query for just the user ID with:

```
var approvals = context.APPROVALS
                       .Where(a => a.APPROVER_ID == CurrentUserID)
                       .ToList();
```

My issue is also checking against the groups that the current user has 'awareness' permissions to.  The best I have been able to come up with is storing a list of the users 'awareness' groups (stored as CurrentUserAwarnessGroups in the example below) and doing something like the following:

```
var approvals = context.APPROVALS
                       .Where(a => a.APPROVER_ID == CurrentUserID || CurrentUserAwarnessGroups.Contains(a.GROUP_ID))
```

This query method fails for me not to mention I am assuming it must perform at least part of this query on the client side which means a much larger (and lengthier) query is returned.

Can anyone suggest a better way to perform this functionality?  I can change my database if necessary.

Comment: Does the error message say something special?

Comment: Look into bitwise comparisons. Similar to [Flag] enums. You can store your group memberships in one column.

Comment: Not clear what `CurrentUserAwarnessGroups` is.

Comment: @MounirMehjoub After 15 seconds I get an exception of 'The underlying provider failed on Open.' and an inner exception of 'Pool connection request timmed out.'

Comment: @JasperKent its is a list of the group id's that the particular user has access to view.

Comment: That error message sounds like nothing to do with your query - it's a connection problem.

Comment: @JasperKent if I remove the group filter from my query it runs fine.  I believe the timeout on my connection is set to 15 seconds and the query is taking too long to run.  Even if I extended the connection timeout, 15 seconds is an unacceptable query time for my application.

Comment: When you say 'list of the group id's' do you literally mean a System.Collections.Generics.List<T>? Better if you actually show the code.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out a better method.  My approach was incorrect.  Rather than trying to query approvals and include the related user, I queried by user and included related approvals purely based on their group.  I determined the approval group will always contain the approver ID therefore I can query the database by group alone and then filter by approver on the client machine.  Additionally, by using bitwise comparisons to control 'membership' as recommended by mxmissile, I am able to simplify my group-to-user table.

My solution looks like:

```
var user = context.USERs
                  .Where(u => u.USER_ID == CurrentUserID)
                  .FirstOrDefault();

var tempUserApprovals = user.GROUPTOUSER.SelectMany("GROUP.APPROVALS");
var userApprovals = new ObservableCollection<APPROVAL>();

foreach(var approval in tempUserApprovals)
{
    foreach(var group in CurrentUsersGroups)
    {
        if(approval.GROUP.GROUP_ID == group.GROUP_ID && ((int)group.MEMBERSHIP & Membership.is_aware == Membership.is_aware || approval.APPROVER_ID == CurrentUserID))
        {
            userApprovals.Add(approval);
        }
    }
}
```